# How does null move up the call stack in recursive functions, if a return value of null is not specified?

Tags: recursion, binary-tree

Hi I'm currently learning about recursive Inorder Binary Tree Traversal using C#. There's one main aspect I cannot understand, in particular with this code below.

```
public void InOrder(BinaryTreeNode node)
    {
        if (node != null)
        {
            InOrder(node.Left);
            Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
            InOrder(node.Right);
        }
    }
```

If I had a Binary tree that looked like this...

```
                       9
                     /   \
                    4    20
                   / \  /  \
                  1  6 15  170
```

I know that eventually by recursively calling Inorder(node.left) I will get to the left leaf of the binary tree i.e. the very end of the tree, where node.left will equal null as there are no more nodes.
The tree would look like this...

```
                       9
                     /   \
                    4    20
                   / \  /  \
                  1  6 15  170
                 /
               null
```

Because node.left = null, the first recursive function

```
InOrder(node.left)
```

will terminate, and

```
Console.Writeline(node.left)
```

will execute

**Printing a value of 1**

Eventually these null values move up the call stack after each node is analysed, and all nodes are printed, the tree starts to look like this, as null value moves up the tree..

```
                       9
                    /     \
                   4       20
                 /   \   /    \
                null  6 15    170
               /  \  / \
            null  null null
```

Eventually all the nodes in the tree are equal to null, and all nodes are printed in order to an output of ...

**1, 4, 6, 9, 15, 20, 170**

What I don't understand is how this null value is moving up the tree, and changing all the nodes that have been analysed to null when there is no return value. Normally there would be a base case like...

```
if (node == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

For this, I understand that null is being returned so will persist/return up the call stack. But for fist block of code above, there is no return statement.

I also find it just as confusing when there is only a return statement without a return value like...

```
if (node == null)
        {
            return;
        }
```

Again there is no return of null specified, so how does this null value move up the tree as each node is evaluated?

There isn't a problem with any of this code, it works as expected, and prints all the nodes of the Binary Tree InOrder. This is more about understanding Recursion, and why the first block of code still works even though a return null value is not specified.

Thanks in Advance for the help.

Comment: Are you able to share a [mcve] so we can see the broader context?

Comment: Hi, I've added more detail to the question, but the code does work as expected. It's not that the code is broken. I'm interested in finding out why it works, and turns all the nodes in the tree into null values, when it doesn't explicitly say return null. It's more about understanding how recursion works.

Answer (score 0):

> there is no return of null specified, so how does this null value move up the tree as each node is evaluated?

The function will still return, even if there is no value to return. It's done executing, so control is passed back to the caller.

```
if (node != null) <- skipped entirely when the node is null
{
    InOrder(node.Left);
    Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
    InOrder(node.Right);
}
```

For the tree you gave, this is what happens at the node with value=1:

1. It's not null, so we go into the if block.
2. We evaluate `InOrder(node.Left)` which is just `InOrder(null)`:

   1. It's null, so the if block is skipped.
   2. We return to the caller, `InOrder(node with value=1)`
3. `Console.WriteLine(node.Value)` prints 1.

etc...

Although you can't 'see' the base case in the code, it's still there :) just implicitly.